# Подгрузка комментариев к посту JS+DJango

Tags: javascript, django, комментарии

Имеется проект соц сети, на главной странице посты и комментарии к ним. Дополнительные посты подгружаются при скроллинге через JS. Комментариев к одному посту может быть очень много, выводить их все не вариант, к примеру к каждому посту я вывожу 3 последних комментария, вопрос как подгружать остальные? Была идея написать отдельно View для ajax-запроса и подгружать таким образом комментарии для отдельных постов, но не понимаю как реализовать хранение информации о том что уже было подгружено для конкретного поста. Как вообще реализован этот механизм подгрузки к примеру в VK?